# Wygwam field not completely loading for one channel entry

Tags: pixelandtonic, wygwam

We have a client site that uses Wygwam 2.7.1 on EE 2.5.3 and we have an issue on only one channel entry, and only for a few people. When the entry is loaded in the CP, certain users just see this:

[image: Screen Shot of Wygwam field]

All other users see the Wygwam field perfectly fine.

This channel entry has a lot of YouTube video embeds in the Wygwam field (about 20 videos). That's the only thing different from the other entries and this is only happening for two users so far on Firefox. There is a js error that only shows up for the users who are having this issue. The error is:

```
TypeError: w.filter is not a function
http://www.siteurl.com/themes/third_party/wygwam/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js
Line 31
```

I can't recreate this same error on any other computer. Has anyone come across this before or has an idea of how to fix it.

Comment: Stephen, is this happening behind any particular network security?  Or on any particular browser/version?  What about add-ons? I've seen extensions like Ghostery cause weirdness of this sort; could there be something like that happening?

Comment: Hi Lisa - sorry for the delayed response. I've been looking into all the browser extensions installed on the machines that are seeing this issue but couldn't find one that was the cause. I finally figured out that there is a video embed on the page that is causing issues and registering as an unsafe operation, which is stopping the editor window from loading. Thanks for your help with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appear to be with a video embed in the Wygwam field. Adobe is registering the SWF file as an unsafe operation and that's causing the editor window to stop loading.